# Reuse common resource parameters within ASP.NET Web API project

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

What is the best approach to reuse the type and name of common resource parameters within an ASP.NET Web API project? Some examples:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetObjects(int rpp, int page, string q, string include)
{
    ...
}
```

Could be implemented as:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetObjects([FromUri] CustomParameterModel)
{
    ...
}

public CustomParameterModel
{
    // results per page
    public int rpp { get; set; }

    // current page
    public int page { get; set; }

    // search terms
    public string q { get; set; }

    // include defined properties
    public string include { get; set; }
}
```

Both approaches described above results in the following URL: objects?rpp={rpp}&page={page}&q={q}&include={include}

This is fine for the objects resource, but not for the files resource for example. The files resource does not need the include parameter.

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetFiles(int rpp, int page, string q)
{
    ...
}
```

How could this be achieved in an elegant way without rewriting the type and name of the parameters?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could write own model binder (http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) which will serve that for you.

Another approach would be to write message handler which could pre process requests (http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/http-message-handlers) and validate your parameters (assign default values etc).

Finally, if you do not mark fields as required (http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api) they could leave with default values, for yours that could be 0 for int or null for int? and null for string.

It is always about the particular case, try different approaches and find best which fits to your needs.